# Undefined referance to class

Tags: c++, qt

I know this has been asked a thousands times, but I'm stumped. I've been looking all over for that last 3 days without a result. I keep getting this error and I can't figure out why.
I've added only the code that I have input / that matters. If I comment out my code the program compiles without a problem. What am I doing wrong???

> CMakeFiles/brewtarget.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o: In function MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
>   MainWindow.cpp:(.text+0xb145): undefined reference to yeastCellCounter::yeastCellCounter()'

**`CODE`**

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "yeastcellcounter.h"

// a whole lot of stuff between these...

yeastCountDialog = new yeastCellCounter();
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
class yeastCellCounter;

// A whole log of stuff between these...

yeastCellCounter *yeastCountDialog;
```

**yeascellcounter.cpp**

```
#include "yeastcellcounter.h"

yeastCellCounter::yeastCellCounter(){}
```

**yeastcellcounter.h**

```
#ifndef YEASTCELLCOUNTER_H
#define YEASTCELLCOUNTER_H

class yeastCellCounter
{
public:
    yeastCellCounter();
};

#endif // YEASTCELLCOUNTER_H
```

This are the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES directive in cmakelist.txt

```
SET(ROOTDIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
SET(SRCDIR "${ROOTDIR}/src")
SET(UIDIR "${ROOTDIR}/ui")
SET(DATADIR "${ROOTDIR}/data")
SET(TRANSLATIONSDIR "${ROOTDIR}/translations")
SET(WINDIR "${ROOTDIR}/win")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SRCDIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src") # In case of out-of-source build.
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/QtDesignerPlugins")
```

Comment: check in CMakeLists.txt .Related header files included r not ,using INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.

Comment: @vinod I've made and edit to include the section that references the include_directories part in cmakelist.txt. It looks right to me, I added all my code the the same section as the rest of the source

Comment: have you added yeascellcounter.cpp (note it misses a t) to cpp list ?

Comment: @CapelliC Where do I do that?

Comment: in CMakeList.txt, near mainwindow.cpp, for example...

Comment: @CapelliC That doesn't exist in the file

Comment: look for set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES

Comment: Please try "add_executable (MyApp yeascellcounter.cpp yeascellcounter.cpp.h ~~.....)", I am not 100% sure on this.

Comment: SET(INCLDIR "${ROOTDIR}/Inc").Please check for header files(Inc directory) and add that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
yeastCountDialog = new yeastCellCounter();
```

It should be:

```
yeastCountDialog = new yeastCellCounter;
```

(Notice the lack of parentheses). The default constructor is always called without parentheses. And also, you need to add "yeastcellcounter.cpp" to the list of cmake sources.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a error of the type `undefined reference to ...` it is a linker error. This means that the compiler has completed it's work and all the object files have been compiled without errors. It's now time for the linker to put all the pieces together into a single file.

In your specific example, it says that it cannot find the definition of the function `yeastCellCounter::yeastCellCounter()`. From the code you have pasted, this function, albeit empty, is clearly defined in the file `yeascellcounter.cpp`.

It looks like your cmakelists.txt file is incomplete. You haven't specified which source files need to be linked together to create your final executable. You need to use the `add_executable` statement for this.

Here's a [simple example](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html)